# Can I add HTML markup via CSS classes?

Tags: html, css

I got a great answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990138/how-to-invoke-a-tooltip-when-hovering-over-idd-html-elements-in-a-browser/) about showing a "hover tip" when over a particular segment of text (plus other helpful tips).

But then I thought: Rather than writing "Title="Bla bla bla bla" in a gazillion places, is it possible to delegate that to the CSS class, like so:

```
.billybob
{
    color: lime;
    Title="this is the title for Billy Bob";
}
```

I have an example of trying that out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/ahrsvkq2/), but no joy in Mudville.

Is it possible, or am I stuck with explicitly adding the Title to every place where a class is referenced in HTML?

Comment: Well technically you can write content using pseudo-element selectors `::before` and `::after` and `conent`property but you won't affect existing attributes, just writing text (or images) in the pseudo-element you're defining. Be carefull using this though, CSS are not the place for content just as HTML is not the place for styling... When dealing with a multilingual site you'll soon discover why it's a bad idea.

Comment: You can use a pseudo element, but I am not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471), and then using the `content` property to achieve this via a pseudo element... for example - http://jsfiddle.net/hs3dok9z/

Comment: As others have said you can using the the pseudo-element 'content'. The real question is should you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get is using a pseudo element.

```
.billybob:before {
    content: 'This is a title for Billy Bob';
}
```

Comment: To supplement your answer.. you could achieve something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ehccngdo/) via a pseudo element. (It's based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471))

Comment: It should be noted that this is not, as the title seems to ask, "HTML markup" - it is text. Also, if you care at all about accessibility, you should be wary of using this to insert important content.

Answer (score 2):

**Sorry you can't**. CSS is a presentation language. It can not be used neither designed to add content `(except for :before and :after pseudo element).`

You can though achieve it with Jquery as

```
$('.billybob').attr('title','this is the title for Billy Bob')
```

Comment: I would mark this as the answer, because I like this solution the best, but since I (wrongly, I reckon) asked specifically about how to do it in CSS, I won't (just give it an uptick).