# How can I remove the generic HTML/CSS tooltip?

Tags: html, css, hover, tooltip

I found out how to add a good hover tip within CSS classes referenced in HTML [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990138/how-to-invoke-a-tooltip-when-hovering-over-idd-html-elements-in-a-browser)

I used a combination of the "title" HTML and lharby's CSS.

I have this CSS:

```
span:hover {
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
span[title]:hover:after {
    content: attr(title);
    background:yellow;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

...and my HTML is like so:

```
<p> . . . I couldn't stood it much longer. Then for an hour it was deadly dull, and I was fidgety. Miss Watson would say,
<span class="watson" title="Miss Watson is speaking">"Don't put your feet up there, Huckleberry;"</span> and <span 
class="watson" title="Miss Watson is speaking">"Don't scrunch up
    like that, Huckleberry set up straight;"</span> and pretty soon she would say, <span class="watson" title="Miss 
Watson is speaking">"Don't gap and stretch like that, Huckleberry why don't you try to
    behave?"</span> ...</p>
```

But I get two hover tips with this:

[image]

I would like to only have one; how can I 86 the smaller white one?

Comment: I think you can in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Title auto-gens the little white one by default](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) so to not activate it I'd use `data-attr` instead of `title` since you are creating your own.

```
span[data-attr]:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-attr);
}
```